# symmetrical array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, rubygems

I have this array:

```
flowers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 3, 4]
```

The user inputs as example `k=5`.i want to get Symmetry array like this :

```
[0, 7, 3, 4 , 0, 7, 3, 4]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2D7D.png)

This is my attempt:

```
flowers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 3, 4]

print flowers
puts " "
puts "What Is Number Of K ?"
k = gets.to_i
flowers.delete_at(k)
print flowers
n = flowers.count
puts flowers.count
for i in flowers do
  if ((flowers.values_at(n - 1)) == (flowers.values_at(k - 1)))
    puts "yyyyyyyyyyyy"
    k -= 1
    n -= 1
  else
    flowers.delete_at(k)
    puts "nnnnnnnnnnnn"
    # flowers.drop(i)
    k -= 1
    n -= 1
  end
end
puts "Done!"
print flowers
```

Any help? how can I do that?

Comment: To do what? Can you explain further what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english. I have modified the question.

Comment: What is `n`? ...

Comment: " I want to remove all elements but the elements at index between k + 1 and n" can you rephrase this ?

Comment: You can see the picture that I've uploaded to explain the problem with details . thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
flowers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 3, 4]
print flowers
puts " "
puts "What Is Number Of K ?"
k = gets.to_i
p flowers.slice(k+1..-1)*2
puts "Done!"
```